# FullText contains word and not part of a word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have a full-text index over a list of urls;

- http://example.com:8080/Api
- http://example.com:8080/Api/CustomController
- http://example.com:8080/

And I am trying to search with a full-text in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM urls WHERE CONTAINS(urls.Url, '"http://localhost:8080/"')
```

But that gives me;

- http://example.com:8080/Api
- http://example.com:8080/Api/CustomController
- http://example.com:8080/

when I only want

- http://example.com:8080/

How can I do this? I still need the capabilities that `CONTAINS` offers, like the `OR`, `AND` and `*`-wildcard

Comment: where url = 'http://localhost:8080/'

Comment: I can't do that, because I still want the other capabilities that `CONTAINS` offers; `CONTAINS(urls.Url, '"http://localhost:49318" OR "http://localhost:8080/Api/Web/Site*"')`

Comment: where url = 'http://localhost:49318' OR url like 'http://localhost:8080/Api/Web/Site%'

Comment: @blam this do still not give me the capabillities that I am going to need. I am looking for something that could mark the end of a string in a contains statement..

Comment: If you are looking for the literal values FTS is probably not your best bet.  Apply a regular index to the column and use that when looking for literals and use the FTS feature when searching on broader criteria.

Comment: What capabilities?   Full text does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform an exact match with contains.

You could rewrite your query as such:

```
SELECT * FROM urls WHERE urls.Url = 'http://localhost:8080/'
   OR CONTAINS(...)
```